# boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)

Tags: android, android-activity, key-events

I'm trying implement this method and i get this mistake:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {app.gestionservicios/android.view.Menu}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

This is my code:

```
Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
        {
            Intent passIntent = new Intent();
            passIntent.setClass(Listado.this,Menu.class);
            startActivity(passIntent);

            return true;

        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

And this mi manifiest.xml:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

I don't know where is this mistake can appear, because in my manifiest.xml is declared the activity menu, and i have the java file Menu. It doesn't show compilation mistake, only execution mistake

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have some sort of a naming clash, because it's looking for `android.view.Menu` instead of **your** Menu class. Maybe you have to qualify the class more fully in your manifest?

Comment: @MyiEye, maybe you are rigth, but ... how can i qualife more the class in my manifiest?

Comment: looks like a wrong import. in the activity from where your code is, search for `import android.view.Menu;`, and replace it with the correct class from your package

Comment: @njzk2 thaks i've remove import.view.Menu but it doesn't woks yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in this code

```
Intent passIntent = new Intent();
passIntent.setClass(Listado.this,Menu.class);
```

Menu is your activity, not android.view.Menu class.

Or you can try next code:

```
Intent passIntent = new Intent();
passIntent.setClass(Listado.this, your_pacakge_name.Menu.class);
```

where your_pacakge_name - is the name of the package where your Menu activity is declared.

Comment: thaks for the code, now it doesn't show any mistake but when i press the key it doesn't change activity